# Github API get repo with exact repo name

Tags: github-api

The get repository api ([link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get-a-repository)) works like "search". For example, when I have "foo-bar" repository and I use `/repos/MY_NAME/foo` it returns `foo-bar`.

There seems to be no option for disabling this lenient repo name.

Search API just returns more than one item that worsk for the `:repo`